# Syncing iOS photos to MacBook - Photo Stream behaviour?

Tags: ios, photos.app, photo-stream

I have upgraded my iPhone to iOS 5 and my MacBook to Lion, so "enjoying" the Photo Stream goodness now.

I have plugged my iPhone in and see that all the photos I have taken have been synchronised to my laptop via Photo Stream already.

Does this mean I do not need to sync them again? I thought Photo Stream was only a temp location and will get removed after some time?

So I think selecting "Photo Stream" in iPhoto shows the temp store, but they are also saved into a Event where they will remain even after being removed from Photo Stream.

Are my assumptions correct, or does it work differently?

Comment: Photo Stream on iOS devices are temporary. Not those on Macs. You can probably find an article on CNET about this, or watch the keynote address for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Photo Stream only saves either your last 30 days' worth of photos or your last 1000 photos, whichever you hit first. However, in iPhoto on the Mac, the "automatic import" feature (which I believe is enabled by default) will automatically copy any photos in your photo stream to your Mac's local hard drive.

> So I think selecting "Photo Stream" in iPhoto shows the temp store, but they are also saved into a Event where they will remain even after being removed from Photo Stream.

Correct (again, as long as you have automatic import enabled. You can double-check the setting in iPhoto preferences).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Photo Stream is a part of iCloud, so any photos you take on your iPhone are wirelessly sent to your computer and will remain there until you delete them, even after they leave Photo Stream.